# How to set a json object as value for a property in a Node?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I'm trying to set a property for a Node, with value as a json object. e.g., property: {jsonObject}. I cannot find any apoc procedure that could solve this problem

I tried using toJson, fromJsonMap etc apoc functions

```
WITH apoc.convert.fromJsonMap(jsonData) as v 
MATCH (n:Node {property1: value})
SET n.property2 = v
RETURN n;
```

Neo.ClientError.Statement.TypeError: Property values can only be of primitive types or arrays thereof

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, in neo4j a property value cannot be a map.

Answer (score 0):

As cybersam says, you can't a map for a property value. However, if it's useful, you can represent them as an array - do bear in mind you'll need to manually format it as such, and retrieve.